# LLVM IR optimization of nested functions

Tags: optimization, nested, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm writing a compiler for a toy functional language by generating LLVM IR code. However, I'm having some issues optimizing cases with nested functions.

Functions and operators are curried, so `y = 10 + 20` is performed as `f = plus(10); y = f(20)`. So far, the LLVM optimization passes have been smart enough to optimize the above to just `ret i32 30`.

Once I added support for nested functions (by lambda-lifting with an additional `env` argument for the free identifiers), LLVM could no longer optimize even simple examples like above.

Here's how the nested functions work: when a nested function is called, every free variable it needs are written into an array of pointers (`env`) and passed to the nested function. The nested function loads `env` and reads each index into a local register. I would expect the optimizer to in-line the call and then eliminate the redundant storing and re-loading of `env`. The optimizer inlines the call but can't eliminate the `env`s.

A minimal example of the original and optimized code is below:

```
declare i8* @malloc(i32)

@x = private constant i32 42

define i32 @main() {
  %env_pass = insertvalue [1 x i32*] zeroinitializer, i32* @x, 0
  %env_pass_ptr = call i8* @malloc(i32 8)
  %env_pass_cast = bitcast i8* %env_pass_ptr to [1 x i32*]*
  store [1 x i32*] %env_pass, [1 x i32*]* %env_pass_cast
  %res = call i32 @nested_func(i8* %env_pass_ptr)
  ret i32 %res
}

define private i32 @nested_func(i8* %env) {
  %env_ptr = bitcast i8* %env to [1 x i32*]*
  %env_val = load [1 x i32*]* %env_ptr
  %my_x = extractvalue [1 x i32*] %env_val, 0
  %val = load i32* %my_x
  ret i32 %val
}
```

Optimizing to:

```
@x = private constant i32 42

declare noalias i8* @malloc(i32) #0

define i32 @main() #0 {
  %env_pass_ptr = tail call i8* @malloc(i32 8)
  %env_pass_cast = bitcast i8* %env_pass_ptr to [1 x i32*]*
  store [1 x i32*] [i32* @x], [1 x i32*]* %env_pass_cast
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds [1 x i32*]* %env_pass_cast, i32 0, i32 0
  %2 = load i32** %1
  %val.i = load i32* %2
  ret i32 %val.i
}

attributes #0 = { nounwind }
```

This example ought to reduce down to just `ret i32 42`. I suspect the problem is with `getelementptr`, which is produced by the optimizer.

Here's some pastes of the full original and optimized code for the expression `10 + 20`: [original](http://pastebin.com/nDqmFnHY), [optimized](http://pastebin.com/xv1ZFnXr)

In this case I could choose to not pass the 'add' function in the environment, as it's a global. However, I would still expect this example to optimize correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was lessened if I instead wrote directly to the indices with `getelementptr`, instead of using `insertvalue`. This came about after finding this other question suggesting [LLVM isn't great at optimizing insertvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948879/llvm-insertvalue-bad-optimized).

After using `getelementptr`, the example above reduces to `ret i32 42` and now more basic arithmetic in my language is reduced to a constant. Methods that use more than one operator (e.g. `(10+20)*5`) still don't reduce completely.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples lack the data layout string. Without this many optimizers are unable to produce decent results - they cannot know the size of the pointer, etc.

See http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#data-layout for more information. I would suggest to grab the data layout string as generated by clang on your platform and paste into .ll as the first step.