# LLVM GEP and store vs load and insertvalue: Storing value to a pointer to an aggregate

Tags: indexing, llvm, llvm-ir

What is the difference between `getelementptr` and `store` vs. `load` and `insertvalue` when storing a value to a pointer to an aggregate type? Is one preferred in certain circumstances? And if so why? Or am I headed entirely in the wrong direction?

### Example:

```
; A contrived example
%X = type {i32, i64}

define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** %argv) {
entry:
  %sX.0 = alloca %X

  ; change the first value with GEP + store
  %val1 = getelementptr %X, %X* %sX.0, i32 0, i32 0
  store i32 42, i32* %val1

  ; change the second value with load + insertvalue
  %sX.1 = load %X, %X* %sX.0
  %sX.2 = insertvalue %X %sX.1, i64 42, 1
  store %X %sX.2, %X* %sX.0 ; I suppose this could be considered less than ideal
                            ; however in some cases it is nice to have the
                            ; struct `load`ed
  ret i32 0
}
```

Interestingly using `llc -O=0 ...` they both compile to the the same instructions. What amounts to the following, which is what I had hoped.

```
movl $42, -16(%rsp) # GEP + store
movq $42, -8(%rsp)  # load + insertvalue
```

### Background:

I was reading the [LLVM Language Reference](http://llvm.org/releases/3.3/docs/LangRef.html) and I was reading about [insertvalue](http://llvm.org/releases/3.3/docs/LangRef.html#insertvalue-instruction). The reference notes the `extractvalue` instructions similarity with [GEP](http://llvm.org/releases/3.3/docs/LangRef.html#getelementptr-instruction) and the following differences.

> The major differences to getelementptr indexing are:
>
> - Since the value being indexed is not a pointer, the first index is omitted and assumed to be zero.
> - At least one index must be specified.
> - Not only struct indices but also array indices must be in bounds.

The following question on StackOverflow also mentions the use of `getelementptr` and `insertvalue`, but for different reasons. [LLVM insertvalue bad optimized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948879/llvm-insertvalue-bad-optimized)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semantically, `load`ing and later `store`ing the entire object is more wasteful. What if it's a huge struct? What if it's an array of structs? GEP allows you to access an exact location in memory where you want to load/store, without the need to load/store anything else.

While the two forms were lowered to the same instructions in your example, it isn't generally guaranteed.